# Count number of words in a Dictionary file in R

Tags: r, dictionary, word-count, quanteda

I am reading in a dictionary into R via the `quanteda` package. This package is preloaded with some great dictionaries, one of which is the Moral Foundations Dictionary that I am interested in. This dictionary has several categories (Farm, Fairness, Ingroup etc.) which are broken down to virtue and vice subcategories.

I want to count the number of words that are in each subcategory for each foundation in R. How can I go about doing that?

For a reproducible example, I can access the Moral Foundations Dictionary (labeled as `data_dictionary_MFD`) by running `library(quanteda.dictionaries)`

Thank you!

Comment: When I run `library(quanteda.dictionaries)` I am told that package does not exist. It does not appear on CRAN. Where did that library come from?

Comment: You would need to use the `devtools` package to install it. See https://github.com/kbenoit/quanteda.dictionaries.

Comment: Can you add a sample of how the word entries look like?

Comment: The subcategories of the MFD I'm getting from https://osf.io/whjt2/ are: 1 care.virtue
2 care.vice
3 fairness.virtue
4 fairness.vice
5 loyalty.virtue
6 loyalty.vice
7 authority.virtue
8 authority.vice
9 sanctity.virtue
10 sanctity.vice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you are looking for, but this probably comes down to terminology.  **quanteda** dictionaries use the terminology of "keys" for the canonical categories (in R, the names of the list elements), and "values" for the patterns used to match words for counting occurrences of each key.

The MFD has two sets of "keys": moral "foundations" such as care, fairness, etc, and "valences" represented by "vice" and "virtue" for each foundation category.  As we have recorded it in `quanteda.dictionaries::data_dictionary_MFD`, however -- in  v0.22 of **quanteda.dictionaries** at least --  the dictionary is flattened to just one level.

We can see this, and count the values in each dictionary "key" that combines here the foundation and the valence, as follows:

```r
library("quanteda")
## Package version: 1.5.2

data(data_dictionary_MFD, package = "quanteda.dictionaries")

# number of "words" in each MFD dictionary key
lengths(data_dictionary_MFD)
##      care.virtue        care.vice  fairness.virtue    fairness.vice 
##              182              288              115              236 
##   loyalty.virtue     loyalty.vice authority.virtue   authority.vice 
##              142               49              301              130 
##  sanctity.virtue    sanctity.vice 
##              272              388

# first 5 values in each dictionary key
lapply(data_dictionary_MFD, head, 5)
## $care.virtue
## [1] "alleviate"   "alleviated"  "alleviates"  "alleviating" "alleviation"
## 
## $care.vice
## [1] "abused"  "abuser"  "abusers" "abuses"  "abusing"
## 
## $fairness.virtue
## [1] "avenge"   "avenged"  "avenger"  "avengers" "avenges" 
## 
## $fairness.vice
## [1] "am partial"  "bamboozle"   "bamboozled"  "bamboozles"  "bamboozling"
## 
## $loyalty.virtue
## [1] "all for one" "allegiance"  "allegiances" "allegiant"   "allied"     
## 
## $loyalty.vice
## [1] "against us"  "apostate"    "apostates"   "backstab"    "backstabbed"
## 
## $authority.virtue
## [1] "acquiesce"   "acquiesced"  "acquiescent" "acquiesces"  "acquiescing"
## 
## $authority.vice
## [1] "anarchist"   "anarchistic" "anarchists"  "anarchy"     "apostate"   
## 
## $sanctity.virtue
## [1] "abstinance" "abstinence" "allah"      "almighty"   "angel"     
## 
## $sanctity.vice
## [1] "abhor"    "abhored"  "abhors"   "addict"   "addicted"
```

To apply this to count the words matching a "key" (the combination of foundation and valence), we can create a dfm and then use `dfm_lookup()`:

```r
# number of words in a text matching the MFD dictionary
dfm(data_corpus_inaugural) %>%
  dfm_lookup(dictionary = data_dictionary_MFD) %>%
  tail()
## Document-feature matrix of: 6 documents, 10 features (10.0% sparse).
## 6 x 10 sparse Matrix of class "dfm"
##               features
## docs           care.virtue care.vice fairness.virtue fairness.vice
##   1997-Clinton           8         4               6             2
##   2001-Bush             21         8              11             1
##   2005-Bush             14        12              16             4
##   2009-Obama            18         6               8             1
##   2013-Obama            14         6              15             2
##   2017-Trump            16         7               2             4
##               features
## docs           loyalty.virtue loyalty.vice authority.virtue authority.vice
##   1997-Clinton             37            0                3              0
##   2001-Bush                36            1               18              2
##   2005-Bush                38            3               33              4
##   2009-Obama               33            1               18              2
##   2013-Obama               39            2               12              0
##   2017-Trump               44            0               20              1
##               features
## docs           sanctity.virtue sanctity.vice
##   1997-Clinton              14             8
##   2001-Bush                 21             1
##   2005-Bush                 16             0
##   2009-Obama                18             3
##   2013-Obama                14             0
##   2017-Trump                13             3
```

**However there is a better way** that makes use of the nested structure of the MFD, but we will need to modify the dictionary object first to make it nested.  As supplied, the MFD is already "flattened".  We want to unflatten it so that the foundations form the 1st level keys, and the valences form the second level keys.  Then, using the `levels` argument in `tokens_lookup()` and `dfm_lookup()`, we will be able to choose the level at which we count matches in our text.

First, recreate the dictionary to make it nested.

```r
# remake the dictionary into nested catetgory of foundation and valence
data_dictionary_MFDnested <-
  dictionary(list(
    care = list(
      virtue = data_dictionary_MFD[["care.virtue"]],
      vice = data_dictionary_MFD[["care.vice"]]
    ),
    fairness = list(
      virtue = data_dictionary_MFD[["fairness.virtue"]],
      vice = data_dictionary_MFD[["fairness.vice"]]
    ),
    loyalty = list(
      virtue = data_dictionary_MFD[["loyalty.virtue"]],
      vice = data_dictionary_MFD[["loyalty.vice"]]
    ),
    authority = list(
      virtue = data_dictionary_MFD[["authority.virtue"]],
      vice = data_dictionary_MFD[["authority.vice"]]
    ),
    sanctity = list(
      virtue = data_dictionary_MFD[["sanctity.virtue"]],
      vice = data_dictionary_MFD[["sanctity.vice"]]
    )
  ))
```

Inspecting this we can see details on the dictionary:

```r
lengths(data_dictionary_MFDnested)
##      care  fairness   loyalty authority  sanctity 
##         2         2         2         2         2
lapply(data_dictionary_MFDnested, lengths)
## $care
## virtue   vice 
##    182    288 
## 
## $fairness
## virtue   vice 
##    115    236 
## 
## $loyalty
## virtue   vice 
##    142     49 
## 
## $authority
## virtue   vice 
##    301    130 
## 
## $sanctity
## virtue   vice 
##    272    388
```

And now we can apply it to our texts:

```r
# now apply it to texts
dfm(data_corpus_inaugural) %>%
  dfm_lookup(dictionary = data_dictionary_MFDnested, levels = 1) %>%
  tail()
## Document-feature matrix of: 6 documents, 5 features (0.0% sparse).
## 6 x 5 sparse Matrix of class "dfm"
##               features
## docs           care fairness loyalty authority sanctity
##   1997-Clinton   12        8      37         3       22
##   2001-Bush      29       12      37        20       22
##   2005-Bush      26       20      41        37       16
##   2009-Obama     24        9      34        20       21
##   2013-Obama     20       17      41        12       14
##   2017-Trump     23        6      44        21       16

dfm(data_corpus_inaugural) %>%
  dfm_lookup(dictionary = data_dictionary_MFDnested, levels = 2) %>%
  tail()
## Document-feature matrix of: 6 documents, 2 features (0.0% sparse).
## 6 x 2 sparse Matrix of class "dfm"
##               features
## docs           virtue vice
##   1997-Clinton     68   14
##   2001-Bush       107   13
##   2005-Bush       117   23
##   2009-Obama       95   13
##   2013-Obama       94   10
##   2017-Trump       95   15
```

Specifying both levels (or the default of `levels = 1:5`) matches what we had originally with the flattened dictionary:

```r
dfm(data_corpus_inaugural) %>%
  dfm_lookup(dictionary = data_dictionary_MFDnested, levels = 1:2) %>%
  tail()
## Document-feature matrix of: 6 documents, 10 features (10.0% sparse).
## 6 x 10 sparse Matrix of class "dfm"
##               features
## docs           care.virtue care.vice fairness.virtue fairness.vice
##   1997-Clinton           8         4               6             2
##   2001-Bush             21         8              11             1
##   2005-Bush             14        12              16             4
##   2009-Obama            18         6               8             1
##   2013-Obama            14         6              15             2
##   2017-Trump            16         7               2             4
##               features
## docs           loyalty.virtue loyalty.vice authority.virtue authority.vice
##   1997-Clinton             37            0                3              0
##   2001-Bush                36            1               18              2
##   2005-Bush                38            3               33              4
##   2009-Obama               33            1               18              2
##   2013-Obama               39            2               12              0
##   2017-Trump               44            0               20              1
##               features
## docs           sanctity.virtue sanctity.vice
##   1997-Clinton              14             8
##   2001-Bush                 21             1
##   2005-Bush                 16             0
##   2009-Obama                18             3
##   2013-Obama                14             0
##   2017-Trump                13             3
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for. Thank you so much! My apologies for not being clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your MFD corpus looks like; if it is the one hosted on [osf.io/whjt2](https://osf.io/whjt2) then the first six lines will look like this (with `mfd`as the name for the data set and `Wordtoken`and `MFDcategory`as my column headers):

```
head(mfd)
    Wordtoken MFDcategory
1  compassion           1
2     empathy           1
3    kindness           1
4      caring           1
5  generosity           1
6 benevolence           1
```

If your aim is just to find out how many words are listed under each of the ten levels of `MFDcategory`, then all you have to do is use `table`for that column:

```
table(mfd$MFDcategory)

  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10 
182 288 115 236 143  49 301 130 272 388
```

That is, there are 182 word tokens for category 1, namely care.virtue, as opposed to 288 tokens for category 2, namely care.vice, and so on. Does this help?